# Axios set header Content-Type to multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I'm trying to make a post request using the Axios library in Javascript like so:

```
axios.post('/businesses', fd, 
                {
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.completeButton = 'Completed';

                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    this.completeButton = 'Failed';
                })
```

If I output the global $_FILES variable on the server-side I get nothing.

Here are the response headers in the console. I don't know why the content type wasn't changed.

[image]

Comment: You were messing up request and response. What you logged is response but not request, the headers of response is not equivalent to headers of request. You need to track request on "Network" tab on developer tools.

Comment: Apologies. You're right. On the server (Laravel) the $_FILES global is still empty.

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen you want to upload file async?

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih yes.

Comment: How are you sending formData?

Comment: var fd = new FormData(); fd('files', filesArray)